# Request of models access is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, model, llama, amazon-bedrock

I am trying to access a llama2 , cohere and jurasic models. but my request is failing again and again. I have change payment methods also but its not working . I am getting below error. I have shared you screeshot for your reference. does amazon bedrock models are working for some location or any location's . Please solve below issue.

I am expecting to resolve below issue

enter image description here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.